# Transformar em ul

Tags: php, html

Olá, tudo bem?

Tem como em PHP pegar um texto formatado com tabs e transformá-lo em uma ul?

```
José
    Dados
        Idade: 30
        Estado Civil: Solteiro
    Hobbies
        Tocar violão
            Rock
            Blues
        Ler
        Viajem
            Praia
```

E gostaria de transformar para ficar assim:

```
    <ul>
        <li>José
            <ul>
                <li>Dados
                    <ul>
                        <li>Idade: 30</li>
                        <li>Estado Civil: Solteiro</li>
                    </ul>               
                </li>
                <li>Hobbies
                    <ul>
                        <li>Tocar violão
                            <ul>
                                <li>Rock</li>
                                <li>Blues</li>
                            </ul>                      
                        </li>
                        <li>Ler</li>
                        <li>Viajem
                            <ul>
                                <li>Praia</li>
                                <li>Montanha</li>
                            </ul>                      
                        </li>                      
                    </ul>               
                </li>
            </ul>       
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: De onde vem esse texto?

Comment: De um cliente, agora não sei como ele faz estes textos, tem algum jeito de pesquisar por tabs, por exemplo, um preg_replace que analisa se tem um tab, ele faz uma rotina, dois tabs faz outra e assim por diante

Comment: Da uma olhada na minha resposta. Eu consegui identificar a tabulação.

Comment: Eu tendei usar REGEX mas não consegui. Talvez o @dvd consiga.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Me parece que a sua resposta matou a questão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso. Criei esse exemplo de forma mais simples, mas eu poderia ter criado uma função recursiva, por exemplo. Fiz mais pelo desafio. =)

Esse é o arquivo **texto.txt** que será lido com `file_get_contents("texto.txt")`

```
José
    Dados
        Idade: 30
        Estado Civil: Solteiro
    Hobbies
        Tocar violão
            Rock
            Blues
        Ler
        Viajem
            Praia
```

Porém, eu fiz um teste usando string, e ele lê normalmente, assim:

```
$string = "José
    Dados
        Idade: 30
        Estado Civil: Solteiro
    Hobbies
        Tocar violão
            Rock
            Blues
        Ler
        Viajem
            Praia";
```

Sem mais... segue o código comentado:

```
$string =  file_get_contents("texto.txt"); // pega o conteudo
$string = explode("\n", $string); // separa as linhas
$array = array();

// cria o array com os níveis com contagem da tabulação
foreach($string as $linha){
    $num_spaces = substr_count($linha, " ");
    $tabs_count = floor($num_spaces / 4); // quantidade de tabulação
    $array[] = array( $tabs_count => $linha );
}

// mostra o menu
echo "<ul>";
for($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++){
    $menu = $array[$x];
    foreach($menu as $key => $val){
        $chave = $key;
        $valor = $val;
    }
    if(isset($array[$x + 1])){
        $next = $array[$x + 1];
        foreach($next as $key => $val){
        $nextChave = $key;
        }
        if ($nextChave > $chave){
            echo "<li>".trim($valor);
            echo "<ul>";
        } else {
            if($nextChave == $chave){
                echo "<li>".trim($valor)."</li>";
            } else {
                echo "<li>".trim($valor)."</li></ul>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "<li>".trim($valor)."</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Obrigado Andrei, ajudou muito man!!!

Comment: @AlêMoraes se precisar chama aqui! noix!

Comment: Mt bom! Parabéns mesmo!